# Get token for not verified email in ASP.NET Web API with two factor authentication enabled

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am working with ASP.NET Web API and I enabled two factor authentication to verify user emails:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
     // ...
     manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
     {
         Subject = "Security Code",
         BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
     });
     manager.EmailService = new EmailService();

     var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
     if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
     {
        manager.UserTokenProvider = 
        new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
            {
                //Code for email confirmation and reset password life time
                TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24)
            };
     }
}
```

I added a class named `EmailService` to the project that sends email verification link and it works fine:

```
public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
        {
            Port = 25,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Host = "mail.myserver.com",
            Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("no-reply@myserver.com", "secret")
        };

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("no-reply@myserver.com", message.Destination);
        mail.Subject = message.Subject;
        mail.Body = message.Body;
        return client.SendMailAsync(mail);
    }
```

Screenshot for new registered user record in database:

[image]

The problem is that in my Android client I can get `Access Token` before validating email and I am able to call service that are restricted with `[Authorize]` with that token. What is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not check for `EmailConfirmed` in `ApplicationOAuthProvider` class. The new `if` statement added solved the problem:

public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager();

```
ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

if (user == null)
{
    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
    return;
}

// This if was required:
if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
{
    context.SetError("email_not_confirmed", "You did not confirm your email.");
    return;
}

ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
   OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
context.Validated(ticket);
context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
```

}